# Get an array of days from mysql table that includes days between From/To dates

Tags: php, strtotime

I apologize if this is a little simple, but I've been googleing and googleing and just can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

I have a calendar script that allows users to upload events lasting more than one day. It stores the events in a mysql database table that stores the from date and to date in separate columns.

When I attempt to pull the dates from the table and store the days as an array, including those between the from/to dates, so that they can be highlighted in the calendar the script times out telling me that it ran out of memory on the line where dates between the from/to dates. Surely that can't be right as the table only holds my test event and it only lasts one week.

There may be an easier way of doing it all together and I wouldn't be at all surprised if there were other problems with my script, so any and all input is very much welcome. Thanks!

Here's the snipet:

```
$FromDate=date("Y-m-d", strtotime($Calendar['FromDate']));
$ToDate=date("Y-m-d", strtotime($Calendar['ToDate']));
while($FromDate < $ToDate){
    // below is the line it times out on.
    $StartDate=date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($FromDate))); 
    $EventDays[]=date("d", strtotime($StartDate));
}
```

Comment: You are not incrementing the `$FromDate`, so `$FromDate < `$ToDate` is always true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a simple endless loop since you never change `$FromDate` or `$ToDate` so the `while(...)` never stops and you run out of memory since you always store the same date again and again.

I think you want to rename `$StartDate` to `$FromDate` to get the behaviour you decried.

Comment: Thank you very much edorian, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP 5.3 then this is a great opportunity to use [DatePeriod](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php).

```
<?php
$start = new DateTime('2011-01-01');
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$end = new DateTime('2011-01-28');
// Modify end by one day, so the end date is included.
$period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end->modify('+1 day'));
$eventdays = array();

foreach($period as $date) {
    $eventdays[] = $date->format('d');
} 

var_dump($eventdays);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you...

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE datum BETWEEN '2011-4-6' AND '2011-4-12';
```

with SQL and then do other stuff with PHP?

Comment: I think he wants an array with `2011-04-1, 2011-04-2, 2011-04-3, 2011-04-4`  for an event that starts on the `1st` and ends on the `4th` so that he can mark the days in the calendar. Not get every event from that timespan. (I might be wrong though)